# Resultado diferente em order by com limit

Tags: postgresql

Estou com problemas nas informações obtidas em 3 queries.

Primeiro um select normal ordenado por data:

```
select      id 
from        app_order o
order by    o.date
; // 30558, 30559, 30560, ...
```

Depois um que deveria me trazer o ultimo registro da query anterior:

```
select      id 
from        app_order o
order by    o.date
limit       1
; // 30558
```

E aqui um problema, se pego os ultimos 3, muda completamente a ordem do resultado:

```
select      id 
from        app_order o
order by    o.date
limit       3
; // 30559, 30560, 30558 -- aqui já muda completamente do primeiro
```

Resolvi o problema adicionando o id ao order by, desta maneira há como criar uma ordem nos resultados

```
order by    o.date, o.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que tem a ver com isso:

> When using LIMIT, it is important to use an ORDER BY clause that constrains the result rows into a unique order. Otherwise you will get an unpredictable subset of the query's rows. You might be asking for the tenth through twentieth rows, but tenth through twentieth in what ordering? The ordering is unknown, unless you specified ORDER BY.

A solução pelo visto é aplicar ORDER BY fora do LIMIT.

Comment: As datas dos 3 primeiros são iguais, como o order by não tem nada mais especifico, acaba gerando uma ordem diferente da esperada, mas não errada, se adicionar o id no order by por exemplo já resolve o problema.

Comment: @NovoK Coloque a query que você fez para resolver o problema, pode ser útil a outras pessoas. Abraços.